# Jquery Animate + fadeInOut element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need is while animate move to top 0 , fadeIn is running , it's also when animate move out fadeOut is running too

anyone can help me to fix this ?

here is my code but not working :

code not working example 1

```
$("#note").fadeIn(2000).animate({ top:"0" }).delay(4000).animate({ top:"-200" }).fadeOut(2000);
```

code not working example 2

```
$("#note").fadeIn(2000, function () 
    {
        $("#note").animate(top,"0px");
    }).delay(4000).fadeOut(2000, function () 
    {
        $("#note").animate(top,"-200px");
    })
```

here is the code that working

```js
$("#note").animate({ top:"0" }).delay(4000).animate({ top:"-200" }); // this is working
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note" align="center" style="position:fixed; z-index:2; background-color:rgba(255,102,102,1); width:80%; max-width:400px; top:-200px;">
 <b>
    <p id="txtnote" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); width:100%; line-height:40px; margin:0">hello</p>
  </b>
</div>
```

if u guys can help me set the div note in center(width) of page it is better else i will use js to calculate then set it on the center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `{queue: false}` attribute while you try to fadeIn to have it run synchronously with the next chained function i.e `animate()` and set `display:none to the #note` div.

**What does setting it to false does?**

Instead of `queuing the fadeIn`, it `removes it from the chain of the functions in the queue` and `runs it along` with whichever function is at the top of the queue now i.e `animate()` in this example below.

To center the div `note`, since you have `already set its position to fixed`, you can just make use of `left set to 50% and translate X axis to -50%` as shown.

**First alternative:**

```js
$("#note").fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'}).animate({ top: "0px",opacity:"1"}, 'slow').delay(1000).animate({ top: "-20px",opacity:"0"}, 'slow').fadeOut();
```

```css
#note {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(255, 102, 102, 1);
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: none;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:-20px;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note" align="center">
  <b>
    <p id="txtnote" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); width:100%; line-height:40px; margin:0">hello</p>
  </b>
</div>
```

**The second alternative:**

- You don't need to set the `display:none` to your #note div.
- Neither you have to make use of fadeIn or fadeOut functions, we make use of opacity and top to animate the content.
- You have to set the `initial opacity of #note` div to '0'.

```js
$("#note").animate({ top: "0px",opacity:"1" }, 'slow').delay(1000).animate({ top: "-30px",opacity:"0"}, 'slow');
```

```css
#note {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(255, 102, 102, 1);
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:-30px;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note" align="center">
  <b>
    <p id="txtnote" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); width:100%; line-height:40px; margin:0">hello</p>
  </b>
</div>
```

**Third alternative: Without using Jquery at all but using animation in CSS**

```css
#note {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(255, 102, 102, 1);
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:-30px;
  left:50%;
  opacity:0;
  animation: effect 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes effect {
    10%  {top:0px; opacity:1;}
    70%  {top:0px; opacity:1;}
    80% {top:-30px;opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note" align="center">
  <b>
    <p id="txtnote" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7); width:100%; line-height:40px; margin:0">hello</p>
  </b>
</div>
```

Comment: @J.WCT No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To center the box horizontally use this css snippet

```
#note {
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

> working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7f49tqvr/